# Where do the terms for graph density come from?

Tags: graph-theory

[image]

$$D=\frac{2|E|}{|V|(|V|-1)}$$

Where do the numerator and denominator come from in the definition of graph density ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Number of edges in graph $G= |E|$

Maximum no. of edges a graph can have with number of vertices $|V|$ is ${|V|\choose 2}=\frac{|V|(|V|-1)}{2}$

Thus graph density= $\frac{|E|}{\frac{|V|(|V|-1)}{2}}=\frac{2|E|}{|V|(|V|-1)}$